# Display message in cart if cart items count is less than 5 in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a bulk discount offer when buying at least 5 products. I'd like to display a message on the cart page if the items count would be less than 5.

How could I get the cart item information in javascript and thereafter display a message?

This is what I have now, but it isn't working:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://myshop.myshopify.com/cart.js',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) { 
        var item_count = data['item_count'];

        if (item_count > 5) {
          document.getElementById("cart-discount-message").innerHTML = "Add more products to get 25% discount";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `item_count > 5` be `item_count < 5`? Assuming `data['item_count']` gives the correct count, of course.

Comment: Your if-statement says `item_count > 5` which means, the user has to put at least **6** items instead for the if-statement to be `true`. You could change it to `item_count < 5` which means 5 or less.

Comment: Yeah, sorry had that wrong, but still the code doesn't work. Under what brackets should this code be?
Now I have it in my .liquid file in <script></script>. Can that be the issue?